# Cassandra DevCenter get Cassandra Version

Tags: cassandra

I use Cassandra dev center to write queries against Cassandra database.

If I was using the cqlsh shell, getting the version of cassandra is very easy. you can just read it when you run the shell. or you can issue queries like

```
show version
select @@version
```

But sadly none of these approaches work when you are using the cassandra devcenter.

Does anyone know how to query the version of cassandra when you are using the devcenter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In DevCenter you should be able to query the system.local table of (whichever) node serves your query:

```
SELECT release_version FROM system.local;
```

ex:
[image]